Why is this odd bullet style happening in OneNote?
I've been using OneNote 365 (desktop app, v2402) for several years. I have several notebooks with many sections and hundreds if not thousands of pages. Almost all using bulleted lists and none of them with any issues.
Suddenly today, creating a page from one specific instance of a recurring Outlook meeting, OneNote starts to use an odd bullet style for bullets that are indented one level. It only happens specifically for notes for this instance of this meeting. I've tried deleting the page and recreating it from the meeting. I've created pages for other meetings without this issue. The meeting itself has not been changed in any way for many moons. The Page is not shared, nor is the Section, nor the Notebook
When I check the bullet style used from the OneNote Ribbon bar it shows that "None" is selected.
The style seems to consist of a vertical bar followed by a box followed by a bullet dot.
In all other pages there is by default the hollow circle bullet style for single indent bullet item. However these are not treated as separate characters, when I try to select them I can only select the whole lot or nothing.
Any known reason to cause this?
How can I stop it doing this and go back to using the "normal" style?
*Note that I know that I can manually change the bullet style myself of course, I want to understand the cause and create the page without any underlying issue.


Sounds like it just shows page markings. You know that button in word that looks like the pi or paragraph symbol that shows all spaces, enters, tabs, etc.

... or you're using an odd / incomplete font.
